# VBScript loop in Excel to enter in SAP GUI

Tags: excel, vbscript, sap-gui

I need to get values from an existing Excel sheet and transfer them t SAP GUI. This is done by an vbscript and works. But I need to get a loop this is where I am struggeling.

The loop should start from the second line.

[image: Excel sample]

The code below is not entering the values into SAP GUI.

Can someone please give an advice?

Thanks in advance.

```
Dim arrExcelValues()
i = 7
x = 0
    
Do Until objExcel.Cells(i,"N").Value = ""
    
    ReDim Preserve arrExcelValues(x)
    arrExcelValues(x) = objExcel.Cells(i, "N").Value
    
    i = i + 1
    x = x + 1

Loop

For Each werk in arrExcelValues

    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "mm01"
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRMMG1-MATNR").text = (objSheet.Cells(46,"F").Value)
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRMMG1_REF-MATNR").text = (objSheet.Cells(46,"F").Value)
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRMMG1_REF-MATNR").setFocus
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRMMG1_REF-MATNR").caretPosition = 8
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 0
    
    ' ************************************* here comes the problem
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtRMMG1-WERKS").text = (objSheet.Cells(werk,"N").Value)
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtRMMG1-VKORG").text = (objSheet.Cells(werk,"O").Value)
    ' ************************************* "erstes" Werk
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtRMMG1_REF-WERKS").text = (objSheet.Cells(6,"N").Value)
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtRMMG1_REF-VKORG").text = (objSheet.Cells(6,"O").Value)
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtRMMG1-VKORG").setFocus
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtRMMG1-VKORG").caretPosition = 4
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    
' ************************************* here comes the problem
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSPR1/tabpSP06/ssubTABFRA1:SAPLMGMM:2000/subSUB5:SAPLZMM_GINCOFIELDS:5802/ctxtMARC-PRCTR").text = (objSheet.Cells(werk,"P") & (objSheet.Cells(38,"P")).Value)
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSPR1/tabpSP06/ssubTABFRA1:SAPLMGMM:2000/subSUB5:SAPLZMM_GINCOFIELDS:5802/ctxtMARC-PRCTR").setFocus
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSPR1/tabpSP06/ssubTABFRA1:SAPLMGMM:2000/subSUB5:SAPLZMM_GINCOFIELDS:5802/ctxtMARC-PRCTR").caretPosition = 6
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/btnSPOP-OPTION1").press
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[15]").press
    
Next
```

Comment: Is there an error message? Where is objSheet defined?

Comment: No, no error message. It enters empty values into SAP and that fails afterwards. As this code is just a snippet at the beginnig of this script all should be defined
`Dim objExcel
Dim objSheet, intRow, i
Set objExcel = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")
Set objSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet`

Comment: I am absolutely sorry...indeed there is an error message (to much trying around) 
it says Typeconflict 800A000D in this line
    `session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtRMMG1-WERKS").text = (objSheet.Cells(werk,"N").Value)`

Comment: What does the content of the variable called werk look like?